# Via SPD2010 workflow is there a way to copy a group under one OU into another group in another OU?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow, active-directory, ldap

Using SharePoint Workflow, is there a way to copy a group under one OU into another group in another OU?

Let's say I have a group called "techOps"in OU=Alpha, OU=Security, DC=domainName, DC=com.
How can I, using SPD 2010 Workflow copy the above mentoned'TechOps" into a group called "AllOps" in an OU=Beta, OU=Security, DC=domainName,  DC=com?
If so how can I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, SPD can't modify your Active Directory. You'll need some AD PowerShell, running on a domain controller, to do this.

One workaround, if you're working with the SP2013 workflow model you can expose a web service, and consume that web service from your workflow. But you'll need to implement that web service yourself.

Comment: Thanks Derek, where can I get info on an AD Powershell to do this? Could it, would it be automated?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx